# ASP.Net core API not working on xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, plesk

I'm having problems developing a mobile Application, every time I try to access my online api that's hosted on Plesk, I get this feedback

{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Date: Tue, 09 Nov 2021 13:06:42 GMT   Server:    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains   Transfer-Encoding: chunked   X-Android-Received-Millis: 1636463477348   X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 404   X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1   X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1636463475097   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin }}

Xamarin Code

```
public static async Task<bool> Login(string email, string senha, string lista)
    {
        var login = new Login()
        {
            email = email,
            senha = senha
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), AppSettings.ApiUrl))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
                request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var task = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                task.Wait();
                var response = task.Result;

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return false;
                var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonResult);
                Preferences.Set("accessToken", result.access_token);
                Preferences.Set("userId", result.user_Id);
                Preferences.Set("userName", result.user_name);
                Preferences.Set("tokenExpirationTime", result.expiration_Time);
                Preferences.Set("currentTime", UnixTime.GetCurrentTime());
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lista))
                    Preferences.Get("IdLista", lista);

                return true;
            }
        }
```

API code

```
public IActionResult Login(inLogin inusuario)
{
    //verifica se o modelo é válido
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors));
    }

    var userEmail = _context.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == inusuario.Email);
    if (userEmail == null) return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
    var hashedPassword = userEmail.Senha;
    if (!SecurePasswordHasherHelper.Verify(inusuario.Senha, hashedPassword))
    {
        return Unauthorized();

    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(GeraToken(userEmail));
    }
}
```

But this also gave the same error

```
 // HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        //httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.ApiUrl);           

        //HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        //HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync( "/api/Autoriza/Login", content);


        //if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return false;
        //var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonResult);
        //Preferences.Set("accessToken", result.access_token);
        //Preferences.Set("userId", result.user_Id);
        //Preferences.Set("userName", result.user_name);
        //Preferences.Set("tokenExpirationTime", result.expiration_Time);
        //Preferences.Set("currentTime", UnixTime.GetCurrentTime());
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lista))
        //    Preferences.Get("IdLista", lista);
        //return true;
```

Someone who uses plesk and has been through this can you help me?
I thank you for your help.

working version

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.ApiUrl);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct url?  Have you tried accessing it from the device browser?

Comment: What url are you using?

Comment: Hi @Jason,I'm testing in the API itself and in postman, it works, but in xamarin forms I have this error, in any operating system.

Comment: https://listaapi.saintssoftwares.com.br/swagger/index.html, url api

Comment: https://listaapi.saintssoftwares.com.br in the xamarin

Comment: is that the actual value of `AppSettings.ApiUrl`?

Comment: for login you would need to append `/api/Autoriza/Login` to the API url

Comment: is that the actual value of AppSettings.ApiUrl? - Yes

Comment: Sorry, I had changed the way the request was made and I ended up forgetting to put the rest of the url

Comment: I reedited the question because I was using the request in another way and even so, I returned the same error

Comment: Postman should generate C# code you can paste into your app to test with.  Either your url is wrong or the payload you are sending does not match what the endpoint expects

Comment: I got it here, thanks for your help

Comment: I recommend adding "Your Answer" below, which shows what you changed, to get this to work. That will make this Q&A useful to future readers.